# Position absolute element: How to make him responsive

Tags: css, position, responsive, absolute

I'm doing image slider with two arrow keys, problem is when I try to change my view-port to smaller. Image slider is changing his size responsively but arrow keys not. Don't know how to attach them to image slider and make them responsive. I've found this problem when switch from monitor to my PC with smaller resolution and right arrow key disappeared.

Here is example of my struggle.
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q57qmtxg/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="slider"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/suIr-M1p8yU/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">           </div>

  <div class="arrows index">
    <a href="#" class="left"><</a>
    <a href="#" class="right">></a>
  </div>
</div>



 .container{

  max-width:1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slider{
  position:relative;
}

.slider img{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.arrows {
  font-size: 3.125em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.arrows .left {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 8em;
  left: 0.4em;
  border: 0.02em solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 0.14em;
  padding: 0em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background: #F2B8A2;
}

.arrows .right {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 8em;
  left: 20.2em;
  border: 0.02em solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 0.14em;
  padding: 0em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background: #F2B8A2;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you giving such a high value to the left property of your right arrow? It would probably work if you use the right property instead:

```
.arrows .right {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 8em;
  right: 0.4em;
  border: 0.02em solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 0.14em;
  padding: 0em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background: #F2B8A2;
}
```

To fix the vertical positioning, you should remove the absolute position of your image. By doing that, your slider will have the same height as your image. You can then position absolutely your arrows inside of the slider ( you'll need to change the html) and it should work

Comment: Yes you are right, now he is keeping his right arrow properly, but after image goes smaller  arrow keys are still at the same position from "top". Is any fix to attach this arrow keys to my image slider, I mean is any possibility to keep them im my image slider no matter how small window is ?

Answer (score 0):

that is because you are giving the arrow right a fixed left space 
i would suggests than instead of `left: 20.2em;` make it `right: 0.4em`
so the final would be :

```
.arrows .right {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  top: 8em;
  right: 0.4em;
  border: 0.02em solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 0.14em;
  padding: 0em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background: #F2B8A2;
}
```

the above part is already answered while i was writing my answer, regarding your comment on making the buttons stick with the image.

the css would be:

```
.container{

  max-width:1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:100%;
  height: auto;
}
.slider{
  position:relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.slider img{
  /* position:absolute;  this is updated*/ 
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.arrows {
  font-size: 3.125em;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.arrows .left {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 1em; //this is updated
  left: 0.4em;
  border: 0.02em solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 0.14em;
  padding: 0em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background: #F2B8A2;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}

.arrows .right {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 1em;//this is updated
  right: 0.4em;
  border: 0.02em solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 0.14em;
  padding: 0em 0.4em 0.2em;
  background: #F2B8A2;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
}
```

and the html would be:

```
<div class="slider"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/suIr-M1p8yU/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="arrows index">
        <a href="#" class="left"></a>
        <a href="#" class="right"></a>
      </div>
</div>
```

by this you would make the buttons as part of the slider, then moving them up from the bottom instead down from the top should fix it for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) You are of course right  but I need to think about it more. In my projec is image slider working through javascript where is my images in slider "fading out" and "in",  this change in html will cause fading out my arrow keys too.

Comment: i don't think the buttons will fade too unless you are fading the hole slider.
you can try fading out only the image in the slider but that would change the slider height and width so the position of the buttons might change but i am not sure of that.

Comment: i just tried it with you js fiddle and it seems that the buttons wont fade out. and the slider width and height are still the same please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/nv8a79ss/